# EF4 linq group item indexing

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have the following ER model:

Entry: Id, UserId, ....
Fact: Id, EntryId, GroupId, DataType, DataValue ...

I have  the following linq query to the EF4 data context:

```
var linq = 
 from entry in DataContext.Entry
 where entry.UserId== User.Identity.UserId
 from fact in entry.Facts
 group fact by new { fact.Entry, fact.GroupId } into g
 select g;
```

I want to assign a index to each of the groups like this:

```
linq = linq.Select((Group,Index) => new {Group, Index})
```

but I get a System.NotSupportedException. Is there any other way to achieve this in linq to ef?

I don't want to resort to linq to objects (e.g. by calling `linq = linq.ToList()`), since I extend the query further down in the code and want it to execute in 1 sql command.

Comment: How do you want to further extend it?

Comment: by doing linq = linq.Where(...), to filter the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to EF cannot use row indexing (select with indexes is not supported). You must do it in linq to objects.

```
var query = // your grouping query;
var linq = query.AsEnumerable().Select((Group,Index) => new {Group, Index});
```

Linq-to-entities supports row indexing internally only if you use `Take()` and `Skip()` methods on ordered queryable but still you can't use row index in the query.